# Find the child DIV's and setting their style

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

```
<div class="pm-dialog">
   <div class="pm-dialog-close">
      <div class="colors-main-content"><span>&times;</span></div>
   </div>
   <div class="pm-dialog-inner colors-main-content" style="margin: 12px 15px 0px 15px;">
      <div>
         <div class="pm-dialog-content">
            <div id="selectLocationProfilePopup">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="pm-dialog-footer">
            <div>
               <div class="pm-dialog-footer-background"></div>
               <div class="pm-dialog-buttonpane"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have a class defined as pm-dialog-inner which has a display:table-row.
I can do it with one line : `$(".pm-dialog-inner > div").css("display", "block")` but that is not what I want.
I want to set the div's style based upon its ID in selector, (as I need to override the style inline) mentioned above with one statement  as below:

My code in javascript using Jquery is the statement below:

```
$('#selectLocationProfilePopup').parent().parent().parent().find(".pm-dialog-inner > div").css("display", "block");
```

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong. Can you refactor the above line of code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Best way would be to give your previous div a class so you can select it easier.  I don't think your div's line up to where you would be able to select the second div easily.  Can you make a jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've idented your HTML, it was very confuse, please verify if it is right.

```
<div class="pm-dialog">          
    <div class="pm-dialog-close">        
        <div class="colors-main-content"><span>&times;</span></div>         
    </div>           
    <div class="pm-dialog-inner colors-main-content" style="margin: 12px 15px 0px 15px;">        
        <div>
            <div class="pm-dialog-content">
                <div id="selectLocationProfilePopup">
                    <div></div>
                </div>              
                <div class="pm-dialog-footer">
                    <div>                             
                        <div class="pm-dialog-footer-background"></div>                    
                        <div class="pm-dialog-buttonpane"></div>                     
                    </div>                   
                </div>                
            </div>              
        </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Using this structure i've used the below code and it works ok, please teste and tell if you want this result.

```
$("#selectLocationProfilePopup").parents(":eq(1)").css("display", "block"); 

$("#selectLocationProfilePopup").parent().find(".pm-dialog-footer").children("div").css("display", "block");
```

Comment: I have also further indented my HTML. I think your mark up looks ok. I will test and let you knowt. thanks in advance friend.

Comment: I was able to set the second parent of div id='selectionLocationProfilePopup' to display:block. But it does not set the div parent of <div class='pm-dialog-buttonpane'>

Comment: @Ruruboy, What do you wanna set in the DIV parent of `<div class='pm-dialog-buttonpane'>`?

Comment: I wanna set display:block like the previous one.

Comment: @Ruruboy, Please see the new edit i've done and tell if you get the expected result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13245/discussion-between-ruruboy-and-marcio-simao)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$('#selectLocationProfilePopup').closest(".pm-dialog-inner").find("div:eq(0)").css("display", "block");
```

Comment: only sets the first DIV with display:block and not the other div's.

Comment: it only sets the first child div and not the other first child DIV.

Comment: I have refactored my question

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
<div class="pm-dialog" />
   <div class="pm-dialog-close">
      <div class="colors-main-content"><span>&times;</span></div>
   </div>
<div class="pm-dialog-inner colors-main-content" style="margin: 12px 15px 0px 15px;">
<div class="pm-dialog-inner colors-main-content pre_content">
  ';        
   <div>
     -> I want to set this style div                 
     <div class="pm-dialog-content ">
        <div id="selectLocationProfilePopup"> content text goes here </div>
     </div>
  </div>
     <div class="pm-dialog-footer">
     <div class="pre_content">
        <div class="pm-dialog-footer-background"></div>
        <div class="pm-dialog-buttonpane"> -> I want to set this div style.
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>​​​
```

Add a class to your previous div.. then select all divs under that except the ones containing "footer" in the class.

```
    $('div.pre_content div').not('div[class*=footer]').css('background-color','red');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Then once you have them filtered correctly set your css to whatever.

http://jsfiddle.net/aZpGU/

Comment: Based  upon my requirement I need to use the selector for ID = selectLocationProfilePopup as what you see is one set of divs. There are many sets of these DIVS which work as overlay but the only difference is the ID as mentioned is unique for each overlay. If I used the general version of getting all those divs then I would be causing an overhead in setting all divs of all sets of DIVS to whatever CSS. Hence I need to select based upon that one unique ID to set the CSS of it.

Comment: If that's how you want it you need to structure it so you can "Select" the elements you need.  Either that or you will have to hard code each element you want to set to a different style